# SAP CCO Java Plugin include external library

Tags: java, sapb1

I am developing plugin for SAP CCO.  I need to communicate with fiscal device from plugin for that i use jSerialComm library. When i call jSerialComm method from my code i am getting

```
InvocationTargetException.<init>(Throwable) line: not available
```

in eclipse and CCO outputs

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fazecast/jSerialComm/SerialPort
```

I included jSerialComm.jar in export but still same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the jar into maven. 
By default it didn't export the include the jar, we have to manually include it.